# How to update same row multiple times with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following information in SAM_Updates table

```
37-529-1    1
13793-1 1
42086-1 1
13793-1 1
```

I am running this query to update the quantity value in a another table (Parts) where the custom labels match.

```
update Parts 
set Parts.Quantity = cast(cast(Parts.quantity as int) - 
cast(SAMS_Updates.quantity as int) as varchar(100))
from SAMS_Updates
where Parts.SAMS_Custom_Label = SAMS_Updates.Custom_Label
```

The problem I am running into is with the value 13793. It is only updating subtracting one from the quantity. I want it to end up subtracting two because there are two separate rows.

Any idea why this is happening? I am using SQL Server express.

Comment: Why are you casting a quantity as varchar?

Comment: When I bulk inserted i needed to make it varchar because data was weird.  I could go in and delete the ones and just convert the column to int though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a join to a subquery that aggregates the `Quantity` in `SAM_Updates`:

```
update p
  set p.Quantity = p.Quantity - su.Quantity
from parts p
  inner join (
    select Custom_Label, sum(cast(Quantity as int)) as Quantity
    from SAMS_Updates 
    group by Custom_Label
    ) su
    on p.SAMS_Custom_Label = su.Custom_Label
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RTUE81736

Assuming each part had 10 `Quantity` prior to the update, this returns:

```
+-------------------+----------+
| SAMS_Custom_Label | Quantity |
+-------------------+----------+
| 37-529-1          |        9 |
| 13793-1           |        8 |
| 42086-1           |        9 |
+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: SqlZim your solution is correct. But why doesn't the join discover two rows to join and update?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Because of Halloween Protection: [Halloween Protection - The Complete Series - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2013/02/21/halloween-protection-the-complete-series.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much. I remember reading about it but I will have to work through Paul White's series on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the exceptional cases where an Iterative Solution is recommended over a Set-Based Solution.  This means making use of the (in most cases inadvisable) Cursor operation to apply modifications one row at a time.  The set-based method to data modification will execute in distinct phases and the new intended value for a record cannot be referenced until after the entire set has completed updating when the statement block execution finishes.

While a sub-query containing an aggregated Quantity grouped over each Part will achieve the basic task performing a modification to the Parts inventory quantities, it doesn't allow for ensuring each of the data-driven updates has completed and won't be reapplied on a subsequent execution of the Parts inventory update process.

However, be aware that using a Cursor may require additional considerations to tune the query appropriately to mitigate the potential performance impact caused by its associated higher overhead.

The following codes outlines how a SQL Cursor can be used to update the same row multiple times:

```
/*Create Base Tables*/
    /*Parts Table*/
        /*Create Table*/
            drop table if exists #parts
            create table #parts
                (idParts bigint identity(1, 1) not null,
                SAMS_Custom_Label varchar(25) primary key not null,
                Quantity int not null default 0 check(Quantity >= 0))  --check assumes backorder logic is separate

        /*Insert Values*/
            insert into #parts
                (SAMS_Custom_Label,
                Quantity)
            values  ('37-529-1', 5),
                    ('13793-1', 5),
                    ('42086-1', 5)

        /*Review Current Parts Quantities*/
            select P.SAMS_Custom_Label,
                P.Quantity
            from #parts P

    /*SAM_Updates Table*/
        /*Create Table*/
            drop table if exists #SAM_Updates
            create table #SAM_Updates
                (idSAM_Updates bigint identity(1, 1) primary key not null,
                Custom_Label varchar(25) not null,  --the #parts table should be reference for referential integrity
                Quantity int not null check(Quantity <> 0),
                partsQuantityUpdated bit not null default 'false')  --Indicates Quantity Update was applied to #parts table

        /*Insert Values*/
            insert into #SAM_Updates
                (Custom_Label,
                Quantity)
            values  ('37-529-1', 1),
                    ('13793-1', 1),
                    ('42086-1', 1),
                    ('13793-1', 1)


/*Parts Inventory Update Process*/
    /*Setup Cursor*/
        /*Operational parms*/
            declare @idSAM_Updates bigint,
                @Custom_Label varchar(25),
                @Quantity int

        /*Create & Open Cursor record set*/
            DECLARE C CURSOR
            FOR (   select SU.idSAM_Updates,
                        SU.Custom_Label,
                        SU.Quantity
                    from #SAM_Updates SU
                    where SU.partsQuantityUpdated = 'false')  --Apply only updates that haven't been performed
            OPEN C

        /*Initiate first fetch record*/
            FETCH NEXT
            FROM C
            INTO @idSAM_Updates,
                @Custom_Label,
                @Quantity


        /*Perform Loop*/
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
                BEGIN
                    /*Apply difference to Parts Inventory Quantity*/
                        update P
                        set P.Quantity = P.Quantity - @Quantity
                        from #parts P
                        where P.SAMS_Custom_Label = @Custom_Label

                    /*Mark current SAM_Updates record as applied to #parts table*/
                        update SU
                        set SU.partsQuantityUpdated = 'true'
                        from #SAM_Updates SU
                        where SU.idSAM_Updates = @idSAM_Updates

                    /*Initiate next fetch record*/
                        FETCH NEXT
                        FROM C
                        INTO @idSAM_Updates,
                            @Custom_Label,
                            @Quantity
                END

        /*Close Cursor*/
            CLOSE C
            DEALLOCATE C


/*Examine Results*/
    /*Updated Parts Quantities*/
        select P.SAMS_Custom_Label,
            P.Quantity
        from #parts P


/*new records added to the #SAM_Updates table will be applied to the parts inventory each time the Parts Inventory Update Process is reran*/
```